# How to display nullable DateTime in ListView using ListViewItem

Tags: c#

I have the following code but it gives me an error.

'System.Nullable ' does not contain the definition for 'ToLongDateString ()' and no extension method 'ToLongDateString' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Nullable ' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I want to display the nullable datetime values in listview.
The Attendence class gets the list of students login data and the Form displays the list of data from the Attendence class.

```
class Attendence  
{
    public Student student{ get; set;}
    public DateTime? login {get; set;}
    public DateTime? logout {get; set;}

    public static List <Attendence> GetList ()
    {
        // return the list of DateTime
    }
}

class Form1 
{

    private void Load ()
    {

        List<Attendence > list= new List<Attendence>():
        foreach (Attendence a in list)
        {
            ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(new String []
            {
                a.student.name,
                a.login.ToLongDateString (),
                a.logout.ToLongDateString ()
            });
        }

        item.Tag = a;
        listView1.Items.Add(item);
    }

}
```

Comment: This might sound silly, but would you mind if I asked you to fix the indentation?

Comment: What error? Don't you mean `ToLongDateString()`?

Comment: Please add the description of the error you are getting

Comment: 'System.Nullable <System.DateTime>' doea not contain the definition for 'ToLongDateString ()' and no extension method 'ToLongDateString' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Nullable <System.DateTime>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Jo should check first what [nullable types are](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/nullable-types/) and how to use them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of .ToLongDateString(), you can use **.HasValue** property with ternary operator.
If Login or Logout having value then it will print value otherwise it will return empty string

Syntax

```
string login= datetime.HasValue ? datetime.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") : string.Empty;
```

In your case code will be

```
List<Attendence > list= new List<Attendence>():
        foreach (Attendence a in list){
            ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(new String []{
                a.student.name,
                a.login.HasValue ? a.login.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") : string.Empty,
                a.logout.HasValue ? a.logout.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") : string.Empty
        });
```

Comment: Zuhbead Thanks for accepting my answer. This is my first accepted answer and Happy coding....

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention what version of `C#` you're using but in 6.0 and above you could just use [interpolated strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/interpolated-strings):

```
var item = new ListViewItem(new String []
{
    a.student.name,
    $"{a.login:MM/dd/yyyy}",
    $"{a.logout:MM/dd/yyyy}"
});
```

In the event that either date is null it will simply show a blank space.